# How to create a glint effect in OpenGL fragment shader?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to create something similar to After Effects's BCC Glint effect.
Here is a picture of the desired effect:

[image: BCC Glint]

Note that this effect should act like a filter on top of a texture and that I do not have any information about the specific lighting conditions.

So far I have tried applying a luminance thresholding effect and blurring out the resulting map with the intention of blending it together with the original image. But that didn't yield the desired results.

Any ideas of how this could be achieved?
Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "didn't yield the desired results" -- please show the result you got. "thresholding and bluring" is pretty much how you'll do the effect, so perhaps the problem is with your implementation details.